# Issues with Multiple MKMapViews in IOS Application

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've been having an issue with having multiple `MKMapViews` in my iOS application.
We are currently using a `TabBarController` for basic navigation. The issue comes up when a `MKMapView`'s annotation's button segues to another view that has a button that leads to another `MKMapView`. The first `MKMapView` works fine with annotations and functionality, but the second `MKMapView` won't add annotations.

I believe the class is linked to the StoryBoard's layout fine since it triggers the `viewDidLoad` function upon the segue. When I step through the `viewDidLoad` function it reaches the `addAnnotation` function call, but the annotations do not get added to the map.

I know the post "[Multiple map views in same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099137/multiple-map-views-in-same-app)" covers a similar issue, but the poster didn't seem too friendly and didn't get any answers due to that.

Please let me know what you think, if you need more information, or if you've implemented multiple `MKMapViews` in your iOS project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at your setup of delegates & IBOutlets to make sure each view is pointing to the right mapview. Then make sure each function uses the parameters it was given, e.g.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    //Only use "aMapView here not "mapView"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. I tried setting it up again and I paid special attention to the IBOutlets and now it's working perfectly. To be honest I feel a little silly now, sorry about the mistake. I just assumed that since the implementation for the second MKMapView worked for the first MKMapView that something else was going wrong. It's always easy to shoot yourself in the foot right? :D